# Reduce deployment size of JS Azure Function App

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I had followed this article a while back https://adrianhall.github.io/typescript/2020/01/12/fixing-functions-deployment/

To reduce the zip  folder size of my JS Azure Function app. I tried to deploy today as normal (I use the azure function extension in VSCode to deploy) however it is getting stuck in the "Creating Zip package..." step. When this happened before I added `node_modules/azure-functions-core-tools` to the .funcignore file which has worked for the last few months. I'm assuming the reason it is stuck is due to the app size being too large.

Having ran the following to determine which node-modules were the largest -

```
du -ks node_modules/*/. | sort -rn
```

I got the following results[image: node module file size]

My question is - can I add  `node_modules/aws-sdk` to the .funcignore file? or is this required in the deployment?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to create a sample function in VS code, tried to publish from vs code to azure function app and got deployed successfully.

***Output of the function running locally***:
[image]
[image]

And I also excluded the `node_modules/aws-sdk` package by using the `.funcignore file` and published the function to the Azure App Service successfully as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

**Note**: There is a [limitation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49629) of azure zip deployment to 2 GB and If your zip deployment file size is more than 2 GB then it will stuck while deploying the FunctionApp.
You can exclude that particular package and publish to Azure without any issues.

Comment: thank you for this! I added node_modules/serverless to the funcignore and got it deploying, but the zip size is around 40MB, It seems to fall over around 45MB. It seems to get stuck on compressing before deployment. I will test adding was to the funcignore and ensure the app functions as expected